# JDBC prepared statements/ refer to prepared in another prepared statements

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am new to JDBC and was a bit confused about the syntax. Say I wanted to create multiples queries ( or views in SQL) and refer to a view to make the subsequent queries, how do I do that with prepared statements?

For example:

```
PreparedStatement first = conn.PreparedStatement("SELECT * FROM clients);
first.execute()
```

**Question** Now can I pass the 'PreparedStatement' reference 'first' in the query I am about to create below?

```
PreparedStatement second = conn.PreparedStatement("SELECT * FROM first WHERE age > 10);
```

Comment: No, you're way off. A `PreparedStatement` has nothing to do with views. It certainly doesn't create a view in the database. Find a tutorial that explains the basics and read through it a few times.

Comment: But how do I use the query generated by one prepared statement in another? Do you know any good tutorials that might explain this please?

Comment: You don't use the "query generated by one prepared statement". `PreparedStatements` produce `ResultSets` or insert/update data in the database. I'm sure any tutorial will do, as long as it's about the basics.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest pattern for JDBC is:

```
try (PreparedStatement first = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE age BETWEEN ? AND ?")) {
    first.setInt(1, 80);
    first.setInt(2, 140);
    try (ResultSet rs = first.executeQuery()) {
         while (rs.next()) {
             int age = rs.getInt("age");
             ...
         }
    }
}
```

This syntax: try-with-resources closes `first` and `rs`, even if you return or an exception is thrown.

And the statements: first and second are entirely independent.

One does not need to keep the prepared statements open for the entire database session.

The execution is best triggered by `executeQuery` for SELECT and `executeUpdate` for UPDATE/INSERT where no ResultSet is yielded.